Repeat Keys settings lost on restart
After upgrading Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.10  on a Raspberry Pi 5 the setting
Settings|Accesibility|Typing Assist|Repeat Keys "ON" 

is not respected on a reboot.  Although the toggle shows as "ON" repeat does not work until I drill down and change the speed and delay.  Then the settings are remembered until reboot or shutdown and start, when they are lost.  This doesn't happen on an AMD64 machine upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 at the same time.
